# Como diferenciar 2 id dentro de un mismo query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

tengo el siguiente quey:

```
$query = "SELECT pedidos.*, users.id, users.nombre, users.email, users.username FROM pedidos  INNER JOIN users ON pedidos.usuario=users.idusuario WHERE (email LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR monto LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR usuario LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR nro_transf LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR ci_nro_cuenta LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR banco_emisor LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR banco_destino LIKE '%$busqueda%') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $init, $limit_end";
```

Y me gustaria saber como puedo sacar el dato users.id ya que lo necesito para una function dentro del mismo while y no quisiera hacer otro query para ello.
Ya tengo dentro de mi while:

```
while($row = $c->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {

              $rowUser = $row['usuario'];
              $rowid = $row['id'];
              //$userid = $row['id.users'];
```

Ya he sacado el id de la tabla como **$row['id'];** y necesito asiganarle el valor a la variable $userid con el valor de la id del usuario y no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses un alias en tu query asi:

```
$query = "SELECT pedidos.*, users.id AS uid,...
```

Y luego lo obtienes asi:

```
$userid = $row['uid'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente usa un alias para esa columna y recuperala utilizando dicho alias. Mira el ejemplo. Se ha renombrado la columna conflictiva a "user_id":

```
$query = "SELECT pedidos.*, users.id user_id, users.nombre, users.email, users.username FROM pedidos  INNER JOIN users ON pedidos.usuario=users.idusuario WHERE (email LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR monto LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR usuario LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR nro_transf LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR ci_nro_cuenta LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR banco_emisor LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR banco_destino LIKE '%$busqueda%') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $init, $limit_end";

$userid = $row['user_id'];
$rowUser = $row['usuario'];
$rowid = $row['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

si en la tabla pedidos hay un campo id tendras problemas la cual sujeriria que hagas lo siguiente:

```
$query = "SELECT pedidos.*, users.id as id_usuario, users.nombre, users.email, users.username FROM pedidos  INNER JOIN users ON pedidos.usuario=users.idusuario WHERE (email LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR monto LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR usuario LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR nro_transf LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR ci_nro_cuenta LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR banco_emisor LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR banco_destino LIKE '%$busqueda%') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $init, $limit_end";
```

y en tu php:

```
while($row = $c->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {

              $rowUser = $row['usuario'];
              $rowid = $row['id_usuario'];
```

Comment: Gracias por la rapida respuesta comprendo la sugerencia pero me sale **Undefined index: uid in /var/www/**

Comment: Listo era que tenia que hacerlo en 2 query en que tiene relacion con el input busqueda y con el que no lo tiene tambien..!

Answer (score 1):

Con un alias lo consigues:

```
$query = "SELECT pedidos.*, users.id as userid, users.nombre, ...;
```

En el while:

```
$userid = $row['userid'];
```

Un saludo